# Express can't read Chunked Post Data

Tags: typescript, express, body-parser

I'm collecting data from a campbell scientific data logger. This data logger post information to app coded in Typescript using Express and BodyParser. The request gets the app (able to debug it), but body/query is and Object{}

In order to be sure that data logger sends data, I did another program, a simple PHP code which dumps the post data and it's headers:

```php
$json_params = file_get_contents("php://input");
$log->lwrite($json_params); 
$headers = apache_request_headers();
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
      $log->lwrite('header:'.$header.' Value:'.$value);
}
```

and the result is:

`[26/Aug/2019:17:10:59] (test - 12452) {"head": {"transaction": 0,"signature": 11786,"environment":  {"station_name":  "idtest","table_name":  "Tabla1","model":  "CR300","serial_no":  "1646","os_version":  "CR310.Std.08.01","prog_name":  "CPU:19014_Badajoz_Inundacion_Dev1.CR300"},"fields":  [{"name":  "Voltage","type":  "xsd:float","units":  "Volts","process":  "Avg","settable":  false},{"name":  "Temp","type":  "xsd:float","units":  "Grados C","process":  "Avg","settable":  false},{"name":  "HR","type":  "xsd:float","units":  "%HR","process":  "Smp","settable":  false},{"name":  "Lluvia","type":  "xsd:float","units":  "mm","process":  "Tot","settable":  false},{"name":  "Distancia","type":  "xsd:float","units":  "cm","process":  "Avg","settable":  false},{"name":  "Calado","type":  "xsd:float","units":  "cm","process":  "Avg","settable":  false}]},"data": [
{"time":  "2019-08-26T17:09:00","no":  0,"vals": [12.26,"NAN","NAN",0,"NAN","NAN"]}]}`

```
`[26/Aug/2019:17:10:59] (test - 12452) header:User-Agent Value:CR310.Std.08.01`

`[26/Aug/2019:17:10:59] (test - 12452) header:Host Value:192.168.1.33`
```

`[26/Aug/2019:17:10:59] (test - 12452) header:Transfer-Encoding Value:chunked`

- Notice that there is a line break in the json, after '"data": [' maybe its a problem? Or the transfer-encoding type?

It means that I'm doing something wrong in my typescript app.

```js
this.app = express();
this.port = port;
this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
this.router = express.Router();
this.router.post(this.path_campbellStation  
this.updateCampbellStationPost);
```

In the same app I collect information from another dataloger that sends data but sending a GET request and works fine (same code).
I don't know if I have to treat it in some other way (BodyParser with  special options) , because when I debug the typescript app, I just can read the header while body, parameters, raw, query... are empty (Object {})

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news everyone!

I got the solution. The way to deal with chuncked requests (therefore the line brake in the PHP code) is implementing its 'on' events:

```
updateCampbellStationPost = (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    var data: string = '';

    const _this = this;
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        request.body = JSON.parse(data);
        const _data = data;
        // DEAL WITH THE DATA
        response.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private').status(200).send('IS ALL RIGHT');
    });

    request.on('error', function (error){
        response.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private').status(400).send('IS FUCKED');
    });
}
```

Thank you!!